# Getting the place name from a marker on Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I am displaying Google map in my fragment with markers.

I want to retrieve place name from marker placed(I am not setting title to the marker).

In the below screenshot I want to retrieve marker with name (**Here Pu. L. Deshpande Vanodhyan**) As I want to display that name in another view.

**I dont want to use Places Api.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get the marker's position's name with the Maps SDK for Android alone. To get the name, you need to use another service such as the [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro) or the [Geocoding API web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start).

If you go for the latter, then I recommend you first call [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getPosition()) method:

```
LatLng position = marker.getPosition(); // returns a LatLng object
```

Then add the value to the (Reverse) Geocoding request as follows:

```
String geoRequest = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + position + "&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
```

Which should give you results with a `formatted_address` for that `LatLng`, e.g. the first result for "40.714224,-73.961452" is "279 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA".

Hope this helps!